# Merge Query in DB2

Tags: sql, merge, sql-update, db2

I need to update few columns in one table with the very convoluted calculation.

I'm not good enough in SQL so I tried to use "with" clause in combination with update, but It threw error.

Then I found a post online which suggested to use MERGE so I came up with Merge query.  But that one was also throwing an error.

So I removed all other column and updating only one column to remove complexity, but no avail still errors

Below is my query, select query inside working perfectly fine.
Please suggest.

```
MERGE INTO TABLE_1 AS O 
USING (
SELECT  ((TO_NUMBER(TABLE_3.Total_Whsle_Price)-TO_NUMBER(TABLE_2.OPT_BASE_WHSLE)) - ((TO_NUMBER(TABLE_3.Total_Whsle_Price)-TO_NUMBER(TABLE_2.OPT_BASE_WHSLE))*TO_NUMBER(TABLE_1.AUC_MILEAGE))/100000 ) as CORRECT_FLOOR_PRICE
FROM TABLE_1, TABLE_2,TABLE_3
WHERE TABLE_2.Primary_ID= TABLE_1.Primary_ID
AND TABLE_2.option_code = 'FSDS'
AND TABLE_1.FLOOR_PRICE <> '0.00'   
and TABLE_3.Primary_ID=TABLE_1.Primary_ID
and TABLE_3.Primary_ID=TABLE_2.Primary_ID
) AS CORRECT
ON(
 O.Primary_ID = CORRECT.Primary_ID 
)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE 
set O.FLOOR_PRICE =CORRECT.CORRECT_FLOOR_PRICE
```

Error is

> An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
>      MERGE INTO ........
>
> DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-199, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=SELECT;VALUES,   DRIVER=3.61.75 [SQL State=42601, DB Errorcode=-199]

Comment: What DB2 version and platform? Is `MERGE` available in that version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead, I think you forgot your identifier in your select statement because after the "ON" statement "CORRECT.Primary_ID" doesn't associate to anything.

```
MERGE INTO TABLE_1 as O 
USING (
  SELECT  ((TO_NUMBER(TABLE_3.Total_Whsle_Price)-TO_NUMBER
    (TABLE_2.OPT_BASE_WHSLE)) - ((TO_NUMBER(TABLE_3.Total_Whsle_Price)
    -TO_NUMBER(TABLE_2.OPT_BASE_WHSLE))*TO_NUMBER
    (TABLE_1.AUC_MILEAGE))/100000 ) as CORRECT_FLOOR_PRICE,
    TABLE_1.Primary_ID AS Primary_ID 
  FROM 
    TABLE_1, TABLE_2,TABLE_3
    WHERE TABLE_2.Primary_ID = TABLE_1.Primary_ID
    AND TABLE_2.option_code = 'FSDS'
    AND TABLE_1.FLOOR_PRICE <> '0.00'   
    AND TABLE_3.Primary_ID=TABLE_1.Primary_ID
    AND TABLE_3.Primary_ID=TABLE_2.Primary_ID
) AS CORRECT
ON(
 O.Primary_ID = CORRECT.Primary_ID 
)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE 
set O.FLOOR_PRICE = CORRECT.CORRECT_FLOOR_PRICE
```